# Adding List<string> to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I created a class library and I am trying to add data from a `List<string[]>` to a DataGridView.

The string is in the format as follows:

> "Test, 1^Glucose^10/24/2013 10:00;Test, 2^BUN^10/25/2013 11:00;Test, 3^BUN^10/25/2013 11:00"

I am passing the string from another program. I then an making it into a list and then trying to add it to the `DataTable` but no such luck. I created the datagridview with four columns.

> Selected - Checkbox
>
> Patient Name - String
>
> Order Name - String
>
> Order Date - String
>
> Reason - Combo Box

I am getting an error:

> the list is greater than the number of columns.

**Note**: I can make the string anyway I want before passing to this program so if I need to do something with the string before passing it to the program, please let me know. Is there an easier way?

I just want the data to display and I will work on the rest of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
public partial class RenewOrders : Form
{
    public static string strMLMPatientData = string.Empty;

    public RenewOrders(string all_patient_data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        strMLMPatientData = "Test, 1^Glucose^10/24/2013 10:00;Test, 2^BUN^10/25/2013 11:00;Test, 3^BUN^10/25/2013 11:00"
    }

    private void RenewOrders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        this.ConvertStringToList(strMLMPatientData);
    }

    private void ConvertStringToList(string strMLMPatientData)
    {
        var patient_list = strMLMPatientData.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split('^')).ToList();
        DataTable dtTable = ConvertListToDataTable(patient_list);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTable;
    }

    // Convert to DataTable.
    static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string[]> patient_list)
    {
        // New table.
        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();

        dtTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Order Name", typeof(string));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Order Date/Time", typeof(string));
        
        foreach (var row in patient_list)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dtTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly post only the relevant stuff always..

Answer (score 3):

First you need to spit the string appropriately to get a list of string arrays. Something like this:

```
var patient_list = new List<string[]>(strMLMPatientData.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(',')));
```

or even better:

```
var patient_list = strMLMPatientData.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
```

You need Linq for that, but you get the idea.

Then you need to add columns to your data table. You cant add rows to it when there are no columns..

Try something like this in your function

```
//add columns appropriately
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Order", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
foreach (var row in patient_list)
    table.Rows.Add(row);

return table;
```

See an example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow). As it stands, your comma separated input string doesnt seem to match your data table column structure. You need to work it out. But I hope you got the idea which way to go.

Comment: No such luck. I still get the error: Input array is longer the the number of columns in the table.

Comment: What is the error you get? Please update the question with a sample `List<string>`. the one you gave is very vague.

Comment: I added what the string looks like in the code. Look for the string strMLMPatientData. I need to split each group by the semicolon and add each item in the group to the grid. Does this help? Would it be easier to pass each string individually, like names, orders, dates?

Comment: @eusanpe how is that possible in the first place? How is `strMLMPatientData` of string type able to hold something like `"Test, 1","Glucose","10/24/2013 10:00";"Test, 2","BUN","10/25/2013 11:00"`? Is that one big string? like `"Test, 1,Glucose,10/24/2013 10:00;Test, 2,BUN,10/25/2013 11:00"`?

Comment: You are right when I think about it. Let me redo this and remove the quotes except in the beginning and the end.

Comment: @eusanpe unless I see an edit on your question and see the exact string type I cant answer. Just to give a direction, you might want `new List<string[]>(strMLMPatientData.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(',')))` for the actual split part.

Comment: I am sorry. I am trying to understand your request for the edit. A sample List<string>? Do you need to know how I need the list to be?

Comment: I am probably going to need to format my string different for splitting since 'Test, 1' is a patient name and it has a comma so it will be split also when it shouldn't be. I need to find another character that is not used.

Comment: @eusanpe exactly. Thats what I thought seeing your string. It doesnt match your columns well.

Comment: I modified the code like your suggestion but I am still getting the error: Input array is longer the the number of columns in the table.

Comment: I got the data to display but it added the columns to my existing DataGridViewer. I will work on this....Thank you @nawfal for all of your help. It is much appreciated....The working code is above.